# How to declare a struct with fields dependent on a previous field?

Tags: matlab

I'd like to elegantly declare structs within Matlab with multiple fields where the second one depends on the first.

Matlab offers multiple ways to declare a struct. One way is by using dot-notation:

```matlab
testStruct.foo1 = 10;
testStruct.foo2 = testStruct.foo1 + 20;
```

The second method is by using the struct-function. I would like to declare it in a way similar to this:

```matlab
testStruct = struct('foo1',10,'foo2',testStruct.foo1 + 10);
```

This will fail, since the foo1 field is not yet available. Is there a way to prevent the dot-notation and declare a struct with fields depending on each other in one line?

Comment: Use a temporal variable. `tmp = 10; ts = struct('f1', tmp, 'f2', tmp+20);`

Comment: Why do you want this at all? This seems like a typical [XY-Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me. Why do want to use a structure at all, when fields are dependent?

Comment: Ha Sven, thanks for the quick reply! I use structs to keep my workspace clean while keeping related variables grouped together. Ideally, i would also like to avoid using a temp variable(could also use that extra line to declare an extra field using dot-notation). I find the existence of the definition of an XY problem instructive and this could definitely be the case here;) !

Comment: What is the use of minimizing the number of lines of code or the number of variables?

Comment: I believe that it could be the case that we are aiming for different things. I understand that it is not a goal in it self to minimize the amount of variables or lines of code. I am curious what the best practice is of keeping your workspace clean. My attempt here is to use a struct for related variables. For example: when storing the variables defining a plot one could use 

examplePlot.min   = 1;
examplePlot.max  = 10;
examplePlot.xaxis = linspace(examplePlot.min,examplePlot.max,50);


Is there a better way to group related variables together?